# Meaning of a certain passage from Charles Dickens Little dorrit Chapter 35

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> *Good gracious, Arthur—Doyce and Clennam!’ cried that lady, ‘who would have ever thought of seeing such a sight as this and pray excuse a wrapper for upon my word I really never and a faded check too which is worse but our little friend is making me, not that I need mind mentioning it to you for you must know that there are such things a skirt, and having arranged that a trying on should take place after breakfast is the reason though I wish not so badly starched*.’

The preceding text is from Little Dorrit by Charles Dickens in Chapter 35 (Book the first). The whole text is difficult to comprehend. What does Flora mean when she says "pray excuse a wrapper for upon my word I really never...?  What is a faded Check? What does the sentence "I wish not badly starched" mean?

Comment: The entire utterance is "breathless excited babble", so there's little or no valid "syntax", and even native Anglophones might struggle to understand the "meaning" of some parts. For example, without more context, I've no idea what ***our little friend is making me*** might refer to. This is hardly the kind of text non-native speakers should be working with. You might as well try to learn English by reading [Finnegans Wake.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnegans_Wake) But at least *not wanting to wear over-starched (too stiff) clothing* is comprehensible to me.

Answer (score 2):

She is probably concerned that the informal garment (wrapper) is not a proper piece of clothing to wear around people. As Flora often does not finish her sentences, she probably meant that she had not expected a visit. "Check" is a fabric characterized by  criss-crossing lines; "faded" means that the colour of the check  is not fresh any more.

Comment: I think she is wearing the wrapper because after breakfast she plans to try on the new skirt that Little Dorrit is making for her. She goes back to her apology for wearing it, adding that she wishes it were not so badly starched (i.e. it looks crumpled as well as being faded).

Comment: @KateBunting I deleted the part concerning the figurative sense of "starch". Maybe you should provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Good gracious, Arthur—Doyce and Clennam!’ cried that lady, ‘who would have ever thought of seeing such a sight as this and pray excuse a wrapper for upon my word I really never and a faded check too which is worse but our little friend is making me, not that I need mind mentioning it to you for you must know that there are such things a skirt, and having arranged that a trying on should take place after breakfast is the reason though I wish not so badly starched.’

The speaker is expressing surprise at some news (or something) about the firm of Doyce and Clennam but she constantly interrupts herself with comments

(i) about the shawl (wrapper) that she is wearing - these comments are in *italics* - and

(ii) with news about her trying on a skirt that is being made for her - these comments are in **bold** -

(The comments in brackets are my translation.)

Good gracious, Arthur—Doyce and Clennam!’
cried that lady,
‘who would have ever thought of seeing such a sight as this -> (I am surprised/impressed by the name Doyce and Clennam)

- *and pray excuse a wrapper* –> (Oh, by the way, I apologise for the poor quality of the shawl that I’m wearing)

for upon my word, I really never -> (I really didn't expect that, i.e. Doyce and Clennam)

- *and a faded check too which is worse* –> (a comment of the pattern of the shawl.)

**but our little friend is making me**,

- **not that I need mind mentioning it to you for you must know that there are such things** -> (although I know that you know about this)

**a skirt**,

**and having arranged that a trying on should take place after breakfast** -> (which I will try on after breakfast)

*is the reason* -> (and that is the reason why I am wearing this shawl)

**though I wish not so badly starched.**’ -> (but the skirt has a small problem: it has been badly starched.)

(**To starch** = To stiffen (cloth, clothes, etc.) with starch. This was a common practice in Dickens' day.)

Comment: Flora is a former sweetheart of Arthur Clennam's, now a middle-aged widow. She keeps on calling him Arthur, and instead of correcting herself 'Mr Clennam' she, absurdly, uses the name of the business he has set up - 'Doyce and Clennam'.

Comment: Thanks, That is context that the OP should have provided.

Answer (score 0):

All Flora's speeches are confused and disjointed. She is embarrassed at his finding her in her checked dressing gown, and a faded and badly-starched (crumpled) one at that, but explains that the reason is that Little Dorrit is making her a skirt (she hesitates to mention a female garment to a man), which she plans to try on after breakfast.